# how to add breadcrumb to devise ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, breadcrumbs

I would like to add breadcrumbs to the signup and login forms (of devise) but I don't know where I add my breadcrumbs to the devise controller?

I have registrations_controller that was inherited from Devise::RegistrationsController and added a breadcrumb to 'edit'.  I tried creating a users__controller (inheriting Devise::UsersController ) but that gave me a circular reference error.

How do I add these breadcrumbs to the users "pages" in devise?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using gem [breadcrumbs on rails](https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails) with devise in my project.

If you haven't made User model with devise make that first:

```
rails g devise User
rake db:migrate
rails generate devise:views users
```

My registration_controller.rb looks like this:

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    add_breadcrumb "home", :root_path
    add_breadcrumb "contact", :contacts_path
end
```

I changed routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

In application.html.erb layout I added breadcrumbs (just above the  <%= yield %> )

```
<%= render_breadcrumbs %>
```

I've just tested it, and it works as you can see from the screenshot.

[image]

**EDITED:**

In case that you want to add breadcrumbs to other pages of Devise gem, for example Forgot your password page, you can make new controller:

```
# app/controllers/passwords_controller.rb
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  add_breadcrumb "home", :root_path
  add_breadcrumb "contact", :contacts_path
end
```

and update your routes:

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: 'registrations',
    passwords: 'passwords'
  }
```

Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: how about adding breadcrumbs to Forgot your password? and other devise pages?  I can't seem to get them to work.

Comment: @JoeGuerra check my edited answer, and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked.   So, basically check the route in the routes table, create a controller for the new path, and add it to the route config file.

Comment: I need one for login, which controller would that be or do I need to create a new one?

Comment: It is the same princip. For example when you run `rails generate devise:views users` and you go to views folder you will see generated views. Take a look the screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/9OCAv 

We only have views, but not controllers. You can see from the Devise views list which controllers we made(PasswordsController, and RegistrationsController) if you want to add breadcrumbs to Login, make new SessionsController, add breadcrumbs, and update routes to:   `devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: 'registrations',
    passwords: 'passwords',
    sessions: 'sessions'
  }`

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the devise views with:

`rails generate devise:views users`

Make sure to replace `users` with whatever your user model name is if it isn't `User` (e.g. `Admin`, `Manager`, etc)

You can then add to those views whatever you need to show breadcrumbs.

Comment: hi, don't I need to define them in the registration controller first?